# How to implement smooth GCD I/O

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Having a rough go here with scheduling disk reads via GCD.

Below is a code snippet to load frames from a file that contains about `frameCount=1000` frames.  In my initial implementation, I did this from the main thread:

```
[self readFramesFromFrame:0 toFrame:frameCount];
```

And here's my method:

```
-(BOOL)readFramesFromFrame:(NSInteger)startFrame toFrame:(NSInteger)endFrame

{
    if (frameCount<=0)
        return YES;

    __block BOOL endRead;

    dispatch_async(diskQueue, ^{
        do {
            dispatch_async(frameQueue, ^{
                for (NSInteger i=startFrame; i<endFrame; i++)
                    [self readFileFrame:i];
            });

            // ** BEGIN get next batch
            NSInteger newStart = endFrame;
            NSInteger newEnd = ((endFrame+highWater) < frameCount) ? endFrame+highWater : frameCount;

            if (newStart==frameCount)
                endRead=YES;
            else
                endRead=[self readFramesFromFrame:(NSInteger)newStart toFrame:(NSInteger)newEnd];
            // ** END get next batch

        } while (!endRead);
    });

    return YES;
}
```

However, I don't want to load up the initial run with 1000 frames as it takes too long.

I initially want to only load 20 frames (my highwater amount), so I rejigged the code and made an revised call of:

```
[self readFramesFromFrame:0 toFrame:(frameCount<highWater) ? frameCount : highWater];
```

But this still takes too long before I get access to the first frame for processing.  I am trying to schedule separate blocks of work rather than one large block of work, but I realize I am still effectively scheduling all frames.  No improvement.

Two points of explanation.  Firstly, my call to `[self readFileFrame:frameNumber]` does a `dispatch_io_read` using a `readQueue`, that is throttled elsewhere by my downstream processing handlers by calling either `dispatch_suspend(readQueue)` or `dispatch_resume(readQueue)`.  I use a low-water value of 10 frames and a high-water value of 20 frames which suspend/resume the `readQueue` as appropriate.  That is working swimmingly well, but is currently predicated upon a reasonably stuff queue of frames.

Secondly, my call to `readFileFrame` will produce a valid frame of data via the `readQueue` thread that is accessed (and displayed) via a separate GCD timer.

I have tried dispatching the code snippet between the comments on "next batch" back on the main queue, but that is a disaster also.  I thought that adding an additional wrapping serial private queue `frameQueue` would help, but no.

If I pretend that `frameCount` is, say, 50 frames, things work very quickly and swimmingly well -- but I only get 50 frames and no more.

**How do I rejig this code snippet so that it lazily reads in batches of frames?**